#  emoji not showing in Flutter application

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm trying to show emojis based on the user's current location and weather.
All my emojis are shown correctly except for the coat emoji ()

I am using the "SpartanMB-Black.otf" font

Here's my code

```
class WeatherModel {
  String getWeatherIcon(int condition) {
    if (condition < 300) {
      return '';
    } else if (condition < 400) {
      return '';
    } else if (condition < 600) {
      return '☔️';
    } else if (condition < 700) {
      return '☃️';
    } else if (condition < 800) {
      return '';
    } else if (condition == 800) {
      return '☀️';
    } else if (condition <= 804) {
      return '☁️';
    } else {
      return '‍';
    }
  }

  String getMessage(int temp) {
    if (temp > 25) {
      return 'It\'s  time';
    } else if (temp > 20) {
      return 'Time for shorts and ';
    } else if (temp < 10) {
      return 'You\'ll need  and ';
    } else {
      return 'Bring a  just in case';
    }
  }
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OnJc.png)

Any reason why?

Comment: but I applied your that coat emoji code line  & it's working. [see_Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKTcj.png).
`Text("Bring a  just in case",style: TextStyle(fontSize:50),),`

Comment: Did you sure the font contain such a emoji? I tried to preview it [online](https://www.freebestfonts.com/spartan-mb-font-family-font), only sun works.

Comment: Here is a new project with a simple Text widget with some emojis and the default font
```
    Text(
              '☀❄❤‍♀️‍♂️‍♀️‍♂️✌‍‍‍‍‍‍✔',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30.0,
              ),
            ),
```
[Screenshot](https://imgur.com/nMTrh7o)
The coat emoji is the only one not showing

I also do happen to have this same [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50892) but I don't know if it has to do with anything.

Comment: Am having a similar issue wherein some emojis are showing and others are not.

`fontFamily: 'Spartan MB'`

Investigated the 'issue' link above; tried the `flutter pub cache repair` and `flutter clean`

Comment: Resolved: it was a `fontSize` issue. Emoji would only show at a size of 85 or smaller

Comment: @chazman no its not related to the font size in my case

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a hardcoded emoji of , try to use the unicode of each emoji's. For , the code is `U+1F9E5` as listed [here](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html). This is how you handle it in Flutter:

```
String coat = '\u{1F9E5}';
```

Sample implementation:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        fontFamily: 'SpartanMB',
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Emoji'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String coat = '\u{1F9E5}'; // U+1F9E5

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Text(
                coat,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 200,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note: I've set `SpartanMB` to be used as a custom font.

Sample output in different platforms:

Android
[image]

iOS
[image]

web
[image]

As you can observed, the output of each emoji is different depending on the platform used. I think using this approach is safer for cross-platform app.

As of to date, Flutter uses the default Emojis supported on a given platform. Therefore, when building a cross-platform app you may face issues of Emojis showing on certain devices and not on others.